# Problem with loading rdlc in report viewer

Tags: report, rdlc, reportviewer, report-designer

Im using a. Net framework 4.7.2 winform app in vs2022. I have installed necessary extension and packeges on my project and created a rdlc report to be shown in report viewer but it seems report viewer cannot find the rdlc and it return error.

I created a new project and tested the same set up and it works perfectly

Also I had to mention I have moved my project folder so does it affect it? My current address is correct in project path

I have tried to create an address and data resource manually in the load event but no success.

Also I should mention it worked once with default setting but not again